# Pure JavaScript select table row as object when click

Tags: javascript

I have a table as following I need when click on a row cell select this row and convert as a JavaScript object using pure JavaScript.

```
<table id="auditors">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It can be any cell or any specific cell that is when clicked changes that row to object?

Comment: Please post your code you have so far and have problems with so we can have a look at it and figure out why it is not working.

Comment: You need to be more specific then `click on a row cell select this row and convert as a JavaScript object` What type of object? You expect the `th` values to be property names of the object with the values of the `tr` you clicked on to be the values? There is a lot of gray area instructions with no visible initial effort being made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interesting part here is to make it generic by not hardcoding the keys/columns. This can be done by using the `th` element texts as keys when building the object:

```js
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#auditors tr"), 1).forEach(function(row){
      row.addEventListener("click", function(){
           var ths = document.querySelectorAll("#auditors th");
           var obj = [].reduce.call(ths, function(obj, th, i){
               obj[th.textContent] = row.cells[i].textContent;
               return obj;
           }, {});
           console.log(obj);
      });
});
```

```html
<table id="auditors">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am just wondering, how does this code dynamically take the values of the first row?

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's just that there's TH only on the first row

Comment: I could see this: `obj[th.textContent] = row.cells[i].textContent;` But not sure how each of the indices are correctly set.

Answer (score 5):

You can do using `addEventListener`:

```js
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++)
  (function (e) {
    trs[e].addEventListener("click", function () {
      console.log(this);
    }, false);
  })(i);
```

```html
<table id="auditors">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here, the `this` will be a `HTMLElement` Object. The logged item will be the `<tr>` itself.

```
<tr>
  <td>Jill</td>
  <td>Smith</td> 
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
```

If you want it to make it like an Object that contains your format, then you need to do:

```js
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++)
  (function (e) {
    trs[e].addEventListener("click", function () {
      console.log({
        "FirstName": this.querySelectorAll("*")[0].innerHTML.trim(),
        "LastName": this.querySelectorAll("*")[1].innerHTML.trim(),
        "Age": this.querySelectorAll("*")[2].innerHTML.trim()
      });
    }, false);
  })(i);
```

```html
<table id="auditors">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When you click the row, you will get the object as:

```
{
  "FirstName": "Jill",
  "LastName": "Smith",
  "Age": "50"
}
```

Here I have assumed the `<th>` as the Object Keys.